# Multiple onResume() when coming back to my activity from Home

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-activity

When I am navigating out from my (main) activity and then coming back by clicking the icon on the Home screen - the activity is automatically Resumed->Paused->Resumed.
I am expecting for only one onResume(). 
My activity creates an AsyncTask in the onResume() function (the activity is not calling to other activities at all) and currently two additional AsyncTasks are created instead of one.
I did some tests and noticed that it happens when this activity is declared as "SingleTask" in the Mainfest. With 'SingleTop" it goes fine and onResume() is called only once.

HELP!

This is my code of the main activity:

```
  public class HomeFinderActivity extends ListActivity implements LocationListener          {
  private TextView latituteField;
  private TextView longitudeField;
  private LocationManager locationManager;
  private String provider;
  private Location location;
  private static final String LOG_TAG = "::HomeFinderActivity->Asynctask";
  private ArrayList<Home> home_parts = new ArrayList<Home>();
  private ListViewAdapter m_adapter;

 /** Called when the activity is first created. */
  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      Intent intent = getIntent();
      setContentView(R.layout.main);
      latituteField = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextView02);
      longitudeField = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextView04);

      // instantiate  ListViewAdapter class
      m_adapter = new ListViewAdapter(this, R.layout.row, home_parts);
      setListAdapter(m_adapter);

      locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

      // Define the criteria how to select the locatioin provider -> use
      // default
      Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
      provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, false);
      location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
  }

  //Asynctask to retrieve cursor from database and sort list by distance
  private class SortList extends AsyncTask<Location, Void, ArrayList<Home>> {
      @Override
      protected ArrayList<Home> doInBackground(Location... location) {
          try {
              if (home_parts.isEmpty()){
                  home_parts=Home.getHomeParts(location[0], getApplicationContext());
          }
              else{
                  for (Home d : home_parts){
                      if (location != null){
                          d.setmDistance((int) (d.getmLatitude()), d.getmLongitude(),(double) (location[0].getLatitude())
                                  , (double) (location[0].getLongitude()));               
                          }  
                  }
              }

          } finally {

          }
          Collections.sort(home_parts, new Comparator(){

              public int compare(Object o1, Object o2) {
                  Home p1 = (Home) o1;
                  Home p2 = (Home) o2;
                  return (int) p1.getmDistance()- (int) p2.getmDistance();
              }
          });
          return home_parts;
      }
      protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<Home> address) {
            m_adapter = new ListViewAdapter(HomeFinderActivity.this, R.layout.row, address);

            // display the list.
            setListAdapter(m_adapter);
      }
  }
      @Override
  protected void onDestroy() {
      // TODO Auto-generated method stub
      super.onDestroy();

  }
  //starting handling location

  /* Request updates at startup */
  @Override
  protected void onResume() {
      super.onResume();
    Log.e(LOG_TAG, "onResume() started");
      if (location != null) {
          onLocationChanged(location);
      }
      else
      {
          latituteField.setText("Location not available");
          longitudeField.setText("Location not available");
      } 

      locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 400, 1, this);
  }

  /* Remove the locationlistener updates when Activity is paused */
  @Override
  protected void onPause() {
      super.onPause();
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "onPause() started");
      locationManager.removeUpdates(this);
  }

  public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
      int lat = (int) (location.getLatitude());
      int lng = (int) (location.getLongitude());
      latituteField.setText(String.valueOf(lat));
      longitudeField.setText(String.valueOf(lng));
      SortList showList = new SortList();
      showList.execute(location);
  }

  public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
      // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  }

  public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
  }

  public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
  }

  /** Called when the user clicks the Add Entry button */
  public void goAddEntry(View view) {
      Intent intent = new Intent(this, AddEntry.class);
      startActivity(intent);
  } 

}
```